# What does ccpNormalize do?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm having a hard time to understand the need of ccpNormalize, the cocos2d reference says it multiplies the CGPoint to 1. I can't just google it that doens't explain it instead of showing in code.

is it that obvious that I can't find it?

feeling stupid here, please help

Comment: makes the length of the (x,y) vector equal to 1.0f, while preserving the angle of the vector.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of normalising a vector is to have magnitude of 1, this is important if you only care about the direction of your vector.

For example maybe you want to keep all your sprite moving at constant speed regardless of any collisions and so you may want to normalise their velocity after the collision and then multiply by you relevant constant speed.

If you are more interested in reading about the subject try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_vector